# Springboot application used TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory vs JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory for uploading large(2 Gb) file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty

My Springboot application used TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory to upload large(2GB) file,now tomcat dependency we are not using, but currently using jetty dependency. So using JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory need to set the file limit-> setMaxSwallowSize(-1) in SpringBoot Application.class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@ComponentScan({ "com.abc" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
@Bean public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbedded() {
     TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    
     tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> { if
     ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)) {
     //-1 means unlimited ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)
     connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1); } });
     }
}
```

Any one can u please help with using JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory in SpringBoot Application.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@ComponentScan({ "com.abc" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

@Bean 
    public JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory1 = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(); // JettyServerCustomizer
      factory1.setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
      return factory1;
 }
}
```

Comment: For jetty you should set ```server.jetty.max-http-form-post-size``` in your application properties.